# Else statement not printing, wondering if I am calling from setter method incorrectly in java

Tags: java, arrays, oop, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a program in java which creates an array. I am trying to have OOP approach. I've made a class file which contains a setter method and my array:

```
public class MenuTestClass{

private int myMonths[];
private double average; //store average value of numbers
private boolean averageCanBeCalculated;
private int max; // store max number from array. to be calculated


public MenuTestClass(){
    myMonths = new int[5];
    }
public MenuTestClass(int[] myMonths){
   this.myMonths = myMonths;
   }
public void setMyMonths(int[] values){ //declare setter method
   myMonths = values;
   }
```

The elements of the array is taken from the user in my main method:

```
       //Menu loop
        int myMonths[] = new int[5];
        int index = 0;
        int num;
        while(choice !=6){


        switch (choice){
            case 1:

            int n = 1;    //int n = number of projects
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many months was your project?");

              for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
               int a = sc.nextInt();

                //if months is lesser than 2/greater than 12
               if((a < 2) || (a > 12)){
                System.out.println("Please enter an amount between 2 and 12 months");}

               //if months is between 2 and 12 add it to the array
               else{myMonths[index++] = a;}
               }

             calc.setMyMonths(myMonths); //creating the object
             break;
```

I am trying to create a function which displays all the elements of the array. If the array is empty I want it to display a message stating this. However, my else statement will not run. I am trying to figure out why this is & am I calling the array incorrectly? Please see my code below:

```
           case 2:
            if(myMonths.length > 0){
                 // print the values
                for(int i=0; i < myMonths.length; i++){
                    System.out.println(myMonths[i] + " ");
                 }

            } else {

                  System.out.println("No values entered");
             }
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance

Comment: null means not instantiated. You instantiated it in the declaration, so it's never null.

Comment: Testing `if(myMonths != null)` at `for(int i=0; i < myMonths.length; i++){ if(myMonths != null){ ` is too late. IF `myMonths` would hold `null` then at `i < myMonths.length` you would end up with `i < null.length` but since `null` doesn't have `length` field (nor any other field or method) it would throw NullPointerException. Based on "`//if the array is not empty display all items`" you are probably confusing `null` with empty array. This is not the same, just like it is not the same as not having a box, or having empty box.

Comment: yeah I was thinking null meant empty.. thanks for clearing that up. Sorry I know these are very basic questions. I've changed it to not empty now (I think) but it is still not executing the else statement

Comment: 'case 2:

    System.out.println("Choice 2: Display all items");
    for(int i=0; i < myMonths.length; i++){
     if(myMonths.length != 0){    //if the array is not empty display all items

     System.out.println(myMonths[i] + " ");
                 }

                     else{System.out.println("No values entered");} //if array is empty display this message

     }


    break;'

Comment: `else` of `if(myMonths.length != 0)` means that `myMonths.length == 0`. BUT in such situation your `for(int i=0; i < myMonths.length; i++)` loop will not iterate even once because `i < myMonths.length` condition at start (where `i=0`) would be evaluated as `0 < 0` which is *false* so loop will stop. This means your `if/else` wouldn't be executed making code inside `else` "dead" (it has no chance of ever getting executed).

Comment: Ah ok, thank you!! So I'm going wrong with the placement of my statements, like which brackets they are in?

Comment: I also just tried using a boolean variable but still no luck.. probably same issue with where I am placing the statements. I'll update my code with the boolean attempt

Comment: Try using ArrayList instead of array. This will handle size changes transparently and has a more intuitive size() method.

Comment: Unfortunately using an array is a requirement of this task. . I need to give my array a certain number of elements, but then this does not allow me to print the else statement if no values where entered. Do you know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code :

```
    for(int i=0; i < myMonths.length; i++){
        if(myMonths.length != 0){    //if the array is not empty display all items

        System.out.println(myMonths[i] + " ");
        }

         else{System.out.println("No values entered");} //if array is empty display this message

        }
```

if `myMonths.length > 0` then it will check for length !!

your code should be:

```
if(myMonths.length > 0){
     // print the values 
    for(int i=0; i < myMonths.length; i++){
        System.out.println(myMonths[i] + " ");
     }

} else {

      System.out.println("No values entered");

}
```

UPDATE:

before you create your Array .. Ask the User for Size,
then you can check if empty or not

```
System.out.println("inter the size:");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int size = sc.nextInt();
int[] arr = new int[size];
if (arr.length > 0) {
  // do your loop
  System.out.println("Not Empty");
} else {
  // Empty array
  System.out.println("Empty");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It still doesn't work though.. do you think it could be because my array is in a setter method in a separate file?

Comment: public void setMyMonths(int[] values){ //declare setter method
    myMonths = values;
    }

Comment: ok .. are u sure you are getting  case 2 ? do you get `System.out.println("Choice 2: Display all items");` ?

Comment: I've added that in again to check, and yeah it's running

Comment: just not carrying out the else statement for some reason, it just prints out a few zeros when I run it after not entering any elements to the array

Comment: because its not empty .. when you create: `int[] v = new int[5] ` ... it will write in memory like this -> ` int[] v = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};`

Comment: omg thank you!! that's solved it. Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: I updated the Answer .. you Are Welcome .. also if you would to choose it as answered .. xd

Comment: Now I am having some issues.. I am using switch statement, when user chooses case 1, they have to give the elements of the array.. when they choose case 2, I need to display all items of the array. I need the array to be accessible to all cases. If I use this method I cannot access the array from other cases, is there a way around this?